# Update data in data source in smart gwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hello all
I am using smart gwt 2.2 on windows system with mozilla browser.
I am using List Grid.In that list grid I am filling the data using data source.
Like this

setClientOnly(true);
super.setTestData(records);

Now on some condition I want to update the records of the grid, so for this I have to update the records of the data source.
I did this by two ways:
1. Created new instance of the data source and fill it with new data and the set this data source to the grid.

But in this it is doubles the fields of the grid.(One field is appearing twice)

2.In this way I remove all the records of the data source of the grid first.By using remove(Record record) method
then set the new data with new records.

But in this issue issues is like this:
17:43:36.328:TMR9:WARN:DataSource:isc_NTDataSource_3:Empty results returned on 'remove' on dataSource 'isc_NTDataSource_3', unable to update resultSet(s) on DataSource isc_NTDataSource_3.  Return affected records to ensure cache consistency.

So how can I update the data of the Data Source or can alter the data with new Data.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getGrid().setData(getGridData(listRecords));
```

Its working for me